# How Python interrupts the current method to execute another method[close]

Tags: python, multithreading, function

In python, I have two methods. In method A, I receive parameters and put them into parameter array. In procedure B, I process the data of parameter array, and put the results of processing into a log array. I want to get the data of reading log data by while loop in final of method A, and get the processing of parameters currently passed into A. As a result, I would like to ask how to pause to start method B when A is half-executed, otherwise A will endless loop.

Adding sleep method expects A to interrupt and B to execute, but it has no effect.

```
def A()
  try:
    datas=request.get_data()
    data=json.loads(datas)
    global queque_list,log_list
    queque_list.append("data":data)
 finally:
    while 1:
       sleep(3)
       if len(log_list)>0
          for logdata in log_list:
             if logdata.get('uuid')==uuid:
                return logdata.get('msg')
def B(task):
   try:
     do(task)
 finally:
     log_list.append({"uuid":uuid,"msg":msg})
def C():
  while True:
    if len(queque_list)>0：
       task=queque_list.pop(0)
       B(task)
t=threading.Thread(target=C)
t.start()
```

I expect if method A can interrupt when executing final module and wait for method B to finish executing before executing.  but now method A executing final module and method B non-execution ,the mothod endless loop

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code consistently and in a way it could actually work. Preferably, adhere to PEP 8 (IIRC), using four spaces. Also, provide a [mcve], as it stands your code is not complete (C in MCVE). BTW: As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue-objects) to send messages between the threads, specifically the put() method to send a message and the get() method to wait for a message in another thread. With this, you can get the threads to work in lock-step.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but perhaps you can get away with doing all the work in a single thread for simplicity.

Comment: Thanks ，Because I need to run batches at the some time, so those can't work in a single thread.Today I solve the problem ,the llist append error